# Azure Active Directory Integrated Authentication with SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I'm quite new to the Azure AD. So I will be grateful for any hint.

I need to enable members of a given domain (of a given Active Directory) to log in to Azure SQL Server using Azure Active Directory - Integrated Authentication.

So far I've logged into Windows and connected it to Azure Acticve Directory in Windows Setting.
[image]

Looking through the documentation, I understand that I need to select one of the authentication methods proposed by Microsoft within Azure Active Directory. The easiest seems to be *Password hash synchronization*. So I would like to pick this one (But if others are simpliest I am open to change that choice)

What is the easiest way to synchronise this? Can I avoid having to create a Windows Server VM and install Azure AD Connect there?

The current configuration of AD Connect on Azure Portal looks as follows:
[image]

To mention it again, the only service I care about is logging in via Azure Active Directory
[image]

I apologise if the whole question has been wrongly structured, but it is simply based on what I have found on the forums and in the documentation.

Thanks in advance for any tips

[for example: https://youtu.be/PyeAC85Gm7w?t=565, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#using-an-azure-ad-identity-to-connect-using-ssms-or-ssdt, https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/azure-ad-pass-through-and-password-hash-authentication-support/ba-p/1269735]

Comment: You don't need Azure AD Connect or password hash sync unless you have an on-premise Windows Server AD that you want to sync to Azure AD. Should note that AD is not the same as Azure AD. You don't need Windows Server AD with Azure SQL, just Azure AD. To grant a certain security group access to the server, you can run `CREATE USER [group-name-here] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;` in the Azure SQL DB. Then you can use standard SQL stuff to grant that "user" access to the DB/tables. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you @juunas very much for the answer. 

I believe I understand, I do not have to use the Azure Connect AD if I do not have a Windows Active Directory which I would like to synchronise with Azure Active Directory. 

But sorry, I do not understand how I can use your solution. I mean, I have created a SQL user with the command 'CREATE ... FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER'. How to allow members of a particular group to log into a database using their AAD accounts? I mean, which Authentication metod should I choose after that 'CREATING USER FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER'? 

Many thanks

Comment: Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA.

Comment: Understand, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Azure AD Connect or password hash sync unless you have an on-premise Windows Server AD that you want to sync to Azure AD. Should note that AD is not the same as Azure AD. You don't need Windows Server AD with Azure SQL, just Azure AD. To grant a certain security group access to the server, you can run `CREATE USER [group-name-here] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;` in the Azure SQL DB. Then you can use standard SQL stuff to grant that "user" access to the DB/tables.

Users should then use *Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA* as the authentication method in SQL Server Management Studio.